# Google Places Autocomplete API implementation error in Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am following [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/) tutorial to implement the auto-complete API from Google Places set of APIs. When extending the class from `ArrayAdapter` and implementing the `Filterable` interface, the Android SDK is not able to resolve the methods shown in the tutorial but rather shows only this method:

```
@Override
public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
       return false;
}
```

The adapter class implementation is shown below:

```
 class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable
    {
        private ArrayList resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index)
        {
            return resultList.get(index).toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter()
        {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public android.widget.Filter.FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
                {
                    android.widget.Filter.FilterResults filterResuts = new android.widget.Filter.FilterResults();
                    if(constraint != null)
                    {
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());
                        filterResuts.values = resultList;
                        filterResuts.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResuts;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, android.widget.Filter.FilterResults results)
                {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                   }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

Here, I get the following errors:

1. The class FilterResults has protected access in class Filter
2. Cannot access values in FilterResults
3. Cannot access count in FilterResults

As well, it doesn't recognize the other methods (`protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)` and `protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)`). I am using KitKat for developing the application.

Comment: You need to show the whole Adapter code. performFiltering and publishResults are abstract methods of Filter. They don't belong to interface Filterable.

Comment: @inmyth ok. But it is fully of errors :(

Comment: Where do you get those errors ? You should just post everything including your attempt to copy that tutorial and the stack trace / log cat of your errors.

Comment: Are you sure you are importing the correct classes? `android.widget.Filter` and `android.widget.Filterable` to be exact.

Comment: @Hassaan thanks :). It was the import problem. Android Studio imported java's logging filter instead of `android.widget.Filter` . Thanks :)

Comment: What alternative to autocomplete API will you be using now that google will block access to this? http://venturebeat.com/2015/07/24/google-will-restrict-access-to-its-autocomplete-api-on-august-10-asks-developers-to-use-custom-search-engine/